MongoDB does not support Unity IL2CPP setup on Android build
The MongoDB system (MongoDB Atlas) does not support Unity's IL2CPP setup on Android.
My build.mongoDB and IL2CPP project is working perfectly in the Unity editor, but it's not working in an Android build.
How do I solve this issue?

What specific symptoms of "not working" do you observe? Do you get a particular error message or log output? A crash? Invalid data read from the database? A failure during the build step? These specifics can be useful clues in isolating the root cause of the issue. It also helps to include in your question a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: the full steps a reader would need to follow to reproduce a small sample of this problem, starting from a new, empty project.

If we select scripting backend - Mono in unity project  (unity-> player settings -> Others -> scripting backend -> Mono) .We can upload and fetch our data from mongoDB If it's mono build else It's not working.

@Varghese_KThomas That's information you should edit into your question. Comments are temporary & limited in size / content; the best way to add key information about your question is in the question itself.
